# IE7 border issue

Tags: internet-explorer-7, styles, border

Im my web page there is a div with width 0 which has a left and right border of 1px width each.

In Firefox when I give the following code it holds the div with 50px width, but it happens to be 48px wide in IE7.

```
<div style="width: 48px; border: #a9a9a9 1px solid; height: 30px;">test div</div>
```

Can anyone help me resolving this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like [IE box model bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug). If in Quirks mode, IE subtracts border, padding, marginfrom element width. See the diagram below:

[image]

If you declare correct DOCTYPE for your HTML, this problem should go away.